# Remove toc when printing rmarkdown site

Tags: css, r-markdown

I've used the super versatile Rmarkdown package to create a [site for a set of seminars](http://biostatistics.dk/seminars/index.html#upcoming_seminars)  extracted and modified using R.

The `_site.yml` file looks like this

```
name: "Seminars at Biostatistics, UCPH"
exclude: ["*.Rmd*", "*.json", "Makefile"]
navbar:
  title: "Seminars @ Biostatistics, UCPH"
  left:
    - text: "Upcoming seminars"
      icon: fa-lightbulb-o
      href: index.html
    - text: "Previous seminars"
      icon: fa-calendar
      href: previous.html      
  right:
    - icon: fa-question fa-lg
      href: http://biostat.ku.dk
output:
  html_document:
    theme: readable
    highlight: textmate
    include:
      after_body: footer.html
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    css: style.css
```

When the page is printed on paper then the table-of-content is overlapping the main text which makes it rather useless.

Is it possible to remove the toc when printing? Either directly through arguments in the yaml or possibly through css and `@media` commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. In your stylesheet:

```
@media print {

  #TOC { display: none; }

}
```

Comment: Whoa that was easy (and simple). Cheers!